# Passing identity from asp.net mvc to WCF services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-security

I'm building a system which will use a web layer (ASP.NET MVC) to connect to a service layer which has multiple WCF services hosted in a windows service.

User will login once to the web layer. Then, according to the function he called, a connection will be made to WCF services. I need to use same user in each service for authorizing user, auditing and logging.

What is the best practice for this? Should I save credentials in Session and each time I need to connect to WCF service and pass those credentials to it?